# Calibrating laptop Dell inspiron t4500 for more faithful colours

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron, color-profiles, calibration

How do I calibrate my Dell laptop to have more faithful colours? I am editing a photo using Photoshop and my Dell laptop, when I am editing I don't encounter any problems with the image or the colour. It's just when it's time to be transfered to other computers it produces a slightly dark image when viewed to my desktop/or other computer.

I am sure there is no problem with my desktop because I transfer images from other sources and put it in my desktop, and never encountered any problem with the colours. Please advice how I can improve my laptop colour settings to have a faithful output.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to improve laptop colors. There is not a lot of software/apps or anything that can improve "hardware" resolution. This laptop is not quite new but not quite old I admit but my solution would be to connect an external display on it.

By that, you would bypass the effect of aging of the laptop screen and your picture would be clearer. If you'd have a workstation, you could change the video card way much easier than a laptop one.

Well, you can also try to download the latest video driver from the manufacturer and then maybe you can set advanced options from their tools but I don't bet that much on this.

Hope that helped you!

David.

Comment: Thanks for taking time on answering my question, I really appreciate it. Yeah, I'll try to update my driver and see if it works. I would also agree on connecting it to an external display.


Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Buy a piece of hardware that measures the colors and brightness of your monitor and which will create a new Color Profile in the Windows Color Management that will resemble reality. 
For example you could buy Spyder2express, which is not very expensive and does the trick very well.